# Get data from db relevant with today, yesterday, today -1.week, today -1.month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a object and a result table

- Object has_many Results
- Result belongs_to Object

Result has a column called `kg`.

I need to get for each `object` the `kg` data

```
where('DATE(created_at) = ?' Date.today AND Date.today - 1.day AND Date.today - 1.week AND Date.today - 1.month)
```

So my question is, which is my best option:

1. Get all the records for 1 month (date Between today and today - 1.month) and then get the result for today, yesterday, 1 week ago and 1 month ago)

   ```
   today = result.where("DATE(created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ?", Date.today - 1.month, Date.today)
   ```
2. Or make 4 queries and get the data for each date?

   ```
   today = result.where('DATE(created_at) = ?' Date.today)
   y = result.where('DATE(created_at) = ?' Date.today - 1.day)
   w = result.where('DATE(created_at) = ?' Date.today - 1.week)
   m = result.where('DATE(created_at) = ?' Date.today - 1.month)
   ```

Comment: What about results that weren't created at the exact dates (e.g 2 weeks ago). They would be included in your first example but not in your second.

Comment: Also, `Object` is an existing class in Ruby that is the parent class of almost all other classes. You should not use that to represent business logic (especially not as an ActiveRecord class).

Comment: My tables have different names, and to answer your first question, I don't need any other dates. So my question is which option is better, the one with I query, which load a lot more records, or 4 queries which load just one row each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you want to later use the results, it might make sense to query them individually using your second approach. That way, you don't have to further separate them in your resultset.

If you don't actually need the data you query in your first approach, it doesn't make sense to retrieve them from the database. You should then use another, more specific approach.

If your actual queries are more complicated that the one shown in the question or if you just want a single result set, it might make sense to use the following approach which just requires one query:

```
dates = [
  Date.today,
  Date.today - 1.day,
  Date.today - 1.week,
  Date.today - 1.month
]

resultset = Result.where('DATE(created_at) IN (?)', dates)
```

This query will result in a SQL query similar to this:

```
SELECT * from results WHERE DATE(created_at) IN ('2013-12-16', '2013-12-15', '2013-12-09', '2013-11-16');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to build an `IN` request.

```
result.where('DATE(created_at) IN (?)', [Date.today, Date.today - 1.day])
```

Which will retrieve the records which are in between the provided dates.

Comment: An `IN` query is not a `BETWEEN` query. The resultset will only contain results what where created at the exact dates (not the ones between them).

Comment: Yes, but if you read carefully his question, what he's looking for is an `IN`, not a `BETWEEN`.

Comment: That's correct. However, your answer reads as if the values given as a value in an `IN` are actually evaluated as if it were a `BETWEEN`. That's the only reason for my comment :)